# django inline creating duplicates

Tags: python, django

I have Django application with multiple models: a main one (Actor) and a number of side ones.

```
from django.db import models

class Actor(models.Model):
    MALE='m'
    FEMALE='f'
    GENDER_CHOICES=(
            (MALE,'male'),
            (FEMALE,'female'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,
            choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name+', '+self.first_name

class Address(models.Model):
    actor=models.ForeignKey(Actor)
    street1=models.CharField(max_length=150,
            help_text='eg. 4112 Corman Ct. SW')
    street2=models.CharField(max_length=150,
            help_text='Field not required',
            blank=True)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100,
            help_text='eg. Los Vegas')
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50,
            help_text='eg. NM')
    zip=models.CharField(max_length=15,
            help_text='12345')

class Contact(models.Model):
    PHONE='ph'
    CELL='cl'
    EMAIL='em'
    OTHER='ot'
    TYPE_CHOICES=(
            (PHONE, 'phone'),
            (CELL,'cell'),
            (EMAIL,'email'),
            (OTHER,'other')
    )
    actor=models.ForeignKey(Actor)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
            help_text='other can be Twitter, Facebook, etc.')
    item=models.CharField(max_length=100,
            help_text='Phone number, Email address, etc.',
            blank=True)

class Picture(models.Model):
    actor=models.ForeignKey(Actor)
    number=models.IntegerField(help_text='Required?')
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=100,
            help_text='Front Pic, Side Pic, etc.',
            blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(help_text='Picture to upload')

    ...
```

I am using `django.contrib.admin` for my admin page.

```
class AdressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model=Address
    extra=1
    fieldsets = [
            ('',
                {'fields':(
                    ('street1','street2'),
                    ('city'),
                    ('state'),
                    ('zip'))}
            )
    ]

class ContactInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Contact
    extra=3
    def get_formset(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        initial=[]
        if request.method=='GET':
            for con in Contact.TYPE_CHOICES:
                initial.append({'type':con[0]})
    formset=super(ContactInline,self).get_formset(request,obj,**kwargs)
    formset.__init__ = curry(formset.__init__,initial=initial)
    return formset
def get_extra(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs): # This was added to see if it fix it but it didn't
    if obj is None:
       return self.extra
    return obj.contact_set.count() - self.extra

class PictureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Picture
    extra=5
    def get_formset(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        initial=[]
        if request.method=='GET':
            initial=[{'number':x+1} for x in range(5)]
        formset=super(PictureInline,self).get_formset(request,obj,**kwargs)
        formset.__init__ = curry(formset.__init__,initial=initial)
        return formset
    def get_extra(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        if obj is None:
           return self.extra
        val = obj.contact_set.count() - self.extra
        return val

    ...

class ActorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('General',
            {'fields':(
                ('first_name','last_name'),
                ('gender','age'),
            )}
    )]
    inlines=[AdressInline,ContactInline,PictureInline, ...]
    radio_fields={'gender':admin.HORIZONTAL}
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None): # another attempt
        return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inlines]

admin.site.register(Actor, ActorAdmin)
```

The problem is when I change an `Actor` object in the admin all of the Inlines have duplicates. For example, AddressInline when data was made on creation in editing the `AdtorAdmin` there is an extra Address object which can't be deleted while the original can. `Contact` and `Picture` have a slightly different issue which I believe is because of `.get_extra()`. The last issue is this happens with the project made in the django tutorial.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer.

```
def get_extra(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs):
    if obj is None:
       return self.extra
    return 0
```